# What does Clojure.Main.exe and Clojure.Compile.exe do?

Tags: clojure, clojureclr

I downloaded [clojure-clr](https://github.com/richhickey/clojure-clr), and I found that it has two execution binaries - Clojure.Main.exe and Clojure.Compile.exe. I see that Clojure.Main.exe is REPL, and I'm not sure what Clojure.Compile.exe does. What do those two tools do exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clojure.Compile.exe let's you compile Clojure code for usage in the CLR, as clojure is a compiled language:

> Clojure is a compiled language - it
>   compiles directly to JVM bytecode, yet
>   remains completely dynamic.

Source: http://clojure.org/

***EDIT***

However in this case, we're dealing with the CLR port, so the end result is meant to run under the .NET CLR instead of the JVM.

The REPL gives you the flexibility of prototyping code quickly, without having to continually go through the compile process to test code changes.

Comment: Isn't that for the CLR not the JVM? The asker is referring the to CLR fork.

Comment: @bmillare yikes, fixed the answer